# How to access OneNote android app content on PC by connecting to PC?

Tags: applications, privacy, offline, microsoft-onenote

Is it possible to use OneNote completely offline and transfer/read it's content on PC manually by connecting mobile device to PC? I don't want to use sync, I want it to be used completely offline and private.

Comment: you should ask Microsoft support. transfer data is possible with adb. read content is another story no one can help you

Comment: AFAIK OneNote is designed to sync only via MS Cloud. Only some old Desktop version(s) can sync using a shared folder on a Windows share.